# Canvas Circle Equation not perfect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing two nested circles and connecting points on their radius together.

I am running into an issue where the points seem to be not perfect .. causing the inner circle outline to look ragged...

ideas... thoughts?

here is the code and example

http://jsfiddle.net/JGWBF/1/

here is the issue ...

[image]

see how some points are actually sticking out ^^^

odd right i think it is due to some subpixel rendering bs

Comment: It looks OK to me. What's the issue exactly? Can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: Zooming in that close may reveal some aberrations, but the normal sized version in your jsfiddle looks right to me. Maybe my eyes aren't so good!

Comment: ok so it looks fine in chrome ... I was testing in the nightly of canary so that probably explains it (facepalm)

Comment: by the way, you don't have to calcul Math.PI/180 (359*4) times. Declaring a var can be better, even if it's not a big deal

Comment: heh good call @DieVarDump ... this has not been optimized yet ... not by a long shot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is anti-aliased. There are plenty of canvas questions on SO about it; in short...

For the basic drawing functions you can't control the anti-aliasing it's browser dependent and seems to be on by default. However, you can circumvent the anti-aliasing with the canvas context pushImageData function.